# How can I limit the capacity of a BufferBlock in C#?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I am using this method to initialize a BufferBlock:

```
var blockOptions = new DataflowBlockOptions();
blockOptions.BoundedCapacity = 1;
_buffer = new BufferBlock<byte[]>(blockOptions);
```

My intentions are to block Post'ing messages after 1 item in the buffer until that item is Receive'd.

However this change does not seem to work that way. Processing stops after 1 message is received. All other messages get discarded.
If I construct the BufferBlock without the constructor parameter my code works fine.

How can I set an upper bound for the size of my message buffer? thanks

Comment: Setting `BoundedCapacity` is the correct way to limit your buffer size. But, nothing is processing your messages. Is the block linked to any other block? If not, the message will just stay in the queue and block it from recieving more messages. [Read](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14782)

Comment: No there are no other blocks.

Comment: I got around the problem by not using BlockBuffer but rather BlockingCollection. This one had exactly the syntax I was looking for and the behavior was just as advertised.

Comment: @JeffSaremi the BufferBlock also works as advertised. It's a block that workes in a pipeline of other blocks. Messages that come from other blocks are *not* discarded. If the BufferBlock can't receive them the source block itself blocks, as it should. You didn't post the code or the block that *produces* the messages or the block that consumes them.